# Add PHP string value to JSON array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I got this:

```
$arr = json_decode($arr, TRUE);
while($row){
    // $arr[] = ['id' => '8', 'name' => 'mickey'];
    $test = $row->TCI_LIBELLE;
    $arr[] = ['id' => $row->TCI_ID, 'name' => $row->TCI_LIBELLE];
    $i +=1;
    $row = $reqCentreInteret->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $json = json_encode($arr);
```

If you don't understand I'm trying to put values I get from a Select SQL query into a JSON array.
The problem is that it does't work like I want.
Indeed it works with my id because in my database it's an int value, but it does't work for the name because it is a varchar value

This is what i want to obtain :

```
[{"id":"8","name":"mickey"},{"id":"8","name":"mickey"}]
```

And here 'mickey' will be replaced by the value of my php string that will be initialized by my sql query

I already tried to solve my problem using

```
'name' => '" .$row->TCI_LIBELLE."'
```

But it does't work

How can I pass string value (or other type) to my JSON array?

I'm using PHP and JSON to send value from MySQL to an Android app.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. Could you show some sample output of your JSON and explain why is it wrong and what you would expect?

Comment: The objective is that in the end i obtain this : [{"id":"8","name":"mickey"},{"id":"8","name":"mickey"], and the value of my php string will replace 'mickey' here

Comment: @WelGalaxy, show `$row->TCI_LIBELLE`, `$row->TCI_ID`, `$row`.

Answer (score 0):

arr[] = adds a new row to the array, i.e. a new top-level element.

You probably want to add your data to the existing element

Let's say your arr initially is something like

```
[ 'property1' => 'value1',
  'property2' => 'value2'
 ...]
```

when you're doing

```
 arr[] = ['id'=> 8,'name' => 'mickey']
```

your array will now contain 2 top level elements and look like

```
  [[ 'property1' => 'value1',
    'property2' => 'value2'
    ...
   ],

   [ 'id'   => 8,
     'name' => 'mickey'
   ]
  ]
```

you may want to do this instead

```
 arr['id'] = $row->TCI_ID;
 arr['name'] =  $row->TCI_LIBELLE;
```

then your arr will look like this:

```
  [ 'property1' => 'value1',
    'property2' => 'value2'
    'id'        => 8
    'name'      => 'mickey'
    ...
  ]
```

Comment: I want my json to look like [{"id":"8","name":"mickey"},{"id":"8","name":"mickey"}], I don't know how to do that, i tried with your solution but it didn't worked, for me the problem is that i can't concatenate the value from my sql query to my json expression

Comment: `var_dump($arr)` after your `$arr=json_decode($arr,true);` and add the output to your question. Let's see what you have there. It could be an array of arrays and then you'll have to add to $arr[0] instead of directly to $arr

Comment: var_dump($arr) give array(0) { }

Comment: are you expecting your array to be empty at the beginning? If so, why are you json_decoding() it?

Answer (score 0):

Finally this is what is had to do

```
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT TCI_ID AS id, TCI_LIBELLE AS nom FROM 
OSO_DEV.T_CENTRE_INTERET");
echo json_encode($stmt->fetchAll(PDO:: FETCH_ASSOC),JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```